# How to recursively explore an array in the chrome console

Tags: javascript, arrays, console, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to find a way to explore Array objects in the *chrome console* (and even other console like *firebug*), as we can easily do for other objects.

Below is the snippet I entered in the chrome console :

```
var str = new String("foo"); str;
var bool = new Boolean(true); bool;
["foo", "bar", str, bool, {}];
```

And the results in the chrome console :
[image: Chrome console explore array snippet]

The only way I could find at the moment is kind of a hack :

```
[["foo", "bar", str, bool, {}]];
```

[image: Chrome console explore array hack]

Is there any option, command or method to just show the inner structure of the array object as it is done by default for other objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what the `console.dir()` function was built for:

[image]

See for more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.dir

http://getfirebug.com/logging

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Answer (score 1):

You can use both [console.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.dir) and [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log) (depending on the current version):

```
var str = new String("foo"); str;
var bool = new Boolean(true); bool;

console.dir(["foo", "bar", str, bool, {}]);
console.log(["foo", "bar", str, bool, {}]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _current version_ ?

Comment: Honestly, i don't know exactly, but I remember that, in older versions, the `console.log` output was a little different

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log(["foo", "bar", str, bool, {}]);

works both in the console and from a script:
[image]

Comment: It appears to work only when the array contains an object. I am not able to achieve it with those array for example : `[1,2]` or ["foo","bar"] ;)