# Use the console to see available methods on an object?

Tags: javascript, browser, console, inspection

Is there any way I can use the console to see the methods available on a JS object?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
> var myArray = [1,2,3];
  undefined
> myArray
  [1, 2, 3]
> myArray.logme = function() { console.log(this); };
  function () { console.log(this); }
> myArray
  [1, 2, 3]
```

The second time I type `myArray`, I would like to see the fact that the `logme()` method is now available.

I want to know the answer in order to explore unfamiliar JS objects more easily.

Comment: If you're referring to Chrome's console, then you could simply type `myArray.` (with the dot) this will reveal `logme` along with all other Array methods

Comment: Have a look a this q/a. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523747/equivalent-of-pythons-dir-in-javascript

Comment: @juco - that's cool, thank you. I don't suppose you know any way to see just the non-Array-prototype methods, though?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
console.dir(myArray);
```

and you will get an expandable/inspectable display like this, including custom properties and the prototype object:

[image]

<sub>(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537759/1048572, see also [What's the difference between console.dir and console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11954152/1048572))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Chrome and you could use something like the following (fairly crude) check for if a property is a `function`:

```
function showMethods(obj) {
    console.log(Object.keys(obj).filter(function(prop) {
        return typeof el[prop] == 'function';
    }));
}
```

Then just call it as follows:

```
showMethods({a: 1, b: 2, c: function () {}}) // ['c']
showMethods({a: 1, b: 2}) // []
showMethods({a: 1, b: function() {}, c: function () {}}) // ['b', 'c']
```